# Theora granulepos when merging two theora video files without sound

Tags: video, ogg-theora

I need merge two files with video (without recompressing video) compressed by theora codec, without sound, to do that i parse each file,
find packets inside, change flag 5 bit in packet header to 0 (continue flag) and set for all packet 
equal serial. This methon works fine, but have some problem with granulepos. Help me please with
granule pos, i try many ways to set it right (set it like miliseconds for example) but this not help.
Tell me please what is granulepos parameter and showind and how i need set granulepos to do than time
 betwen each frame be 300 milisec? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the [OggCat tool](http://dev.streamnik.de/78.html) from Ogg Video Tool allows you to do this without recompressing the video. Note, both files need to have the same attributes (framerate, framesize, etc). It is an open-source project so you can look through the pertinent code relating to concatenating Theora video.

Comment: Tanks! I look on source OggCat tool and i try do like there, no copy-paste just try to apply on my code OggCat logic, but unfortunately on this dont help. OggCat use granulepos like milsecond timer, but when i aplly this logic to my videos, result is now right. Anyway Thanks, i look on OggCat one more time!